# Problem to create a N-ary tree class python

Tags: python, data-structures, hierarchical-clustering

I'm working on text corpus clustering and what I want to do is :
- Divide the corpus into a custom number of clusters
- Then for each cluster, divide it again into more clusters, until some internal criterion is violated.

Now I have implemented the way to cluster a set of documents, but I was wondering if there was some pre-implemented optimized data structure for containing all the hierarchy in Python, like the linkage matrix in `scipy.cluster.hierarchy` for the ascendant hierarchical clustering?

Thanks !

EDIT : 
I began to implement a class designed to my problem but I have a problem :

```
class ClustNode():
    def __init__(self, indices, sons=[]):
        self.sons = sons
        self.indices = indices

    def divide(self, X):
        km = KMeans(n_clusters=2, max_iter=100, n_init=1)
        km.fit(X[self.indices, :])

        for k in range(km.n_clusters):
            subclust_ind = self.indices[km.labels_ == k]
            self.sons.append(ClustNode(subclust_ind))
```

I have a problem at the dividing step : when I add a new son based on the Kmeans division (for now I choose the number of clusters manually) in the `divide` function, the new son created will have itself in his `self.sons`attribute !
For example, the following code :

```
X = np.random.random(size=(100, 5))
n = len(X)    
z = ClustNode(np.arange(n))
z.divide(X)
```

then `z.sons` will contain its 2 `ClustNode` objects but `z.sons[0].sons` and `z.sons[0].sons[0].sons` too and so on...

I don't understand why, can you guys help me ?